# Keep the data when the user back to a previous view - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-local-storage

I have implemented an application where I display a list of results then I allow to the user to select the rows to compare and show some extra data about them.

I'm using `angular ui route` and I have 2 views and 2 controllers one for each, so what I'm looking for is the best way to keep the information in the first view(where I have all the results before to go to the comparison view) when the user back to the first view.

So far what I have tried is use a `$localstorage` but in the first view I have a form where the user can filter the search criterias and also I have some `<select></select>` that are load by an `ajax` call, so.. with the `$localstorage` I keep the information but does not set the form details for the `select input` because the ajax call has not executed, and I don't want keep the local storage always, only in the case when the user back to the previews.

Below you can see the settings for the `angular route ui`:

```
  .state('deposit', {
    url: '/deposit',
    templateUrl: './app/components/deposit/index.html',
    views: { "" : { templateUrl: './app/components/deposit/index.html' },
      "search@deposit": { templateUrl: "./app/components/deposit/search.html",
                            controller: "DepositSearchController"}
    }
  })
  .state('depositcomparison', {
    url: "/deposit/comparison",
    params: {
      ids: null,
      depositSearchData: null
    },
    templateUrl: './app/components/depositComparison/depositComparisonView.html',
    controller: 'DepositComparisonController'
  })
```

What is the proper way to keep the data only when I back from the comparison view to the result view?

is there a way better than the `localstorage`?

Thanks.

/*********** Update ***********/
/*********** Problem with the ajax ***********/

Get data for the select:

```
//...
$http.get(window.serviceUrl + '/api/institute').
  success(function(data){
    $scope.institutes = data.content;
    $scope.institutes.push({id: '0', name: 'All'});
    $localstorage.setObject('instituteData', $scope.institutes);
  }).
  error(function(data){
    console.log('Error');
  });
 //..
```

Check `localstorage`:

```
//..
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    if ($localstorage.getObject('instituteData').length !== 0) {
         $scope.institutes = $localstorage.getObject('instituteData');
      }
    //else call the ajax
//..
});
```

Html:

```
<label for="forinstitute">Account Type</label>
<select id="instituteValue" class="form-control" ng-model="institute.id">
<option value=""> Select account</option>
<option ng-repeat="institute in institutes | orderBy:'name'" value="{{institute .id}}">{{institute .name}}</option>
</select>
```

/********************************************************/

could be a solution the `$watch`??

Comment: You should define the route that resolves the list of the results as the parent of the route that does the comparison (make sure you implement the resolve part of your ui-router state to get the list of results).  That list of results will then be available to the child route (the comparison) and when you navigate between them a reload will not be necessary.

Comment: Well.. why is localstorage the best option, and how can I fix the problem with the ajax call? @Fals

Comment: @gon250 You can get the value selected from the localstorage and then set the ng-model for the select inside the promisse that populates the select from $http.

Comment: @Fals let me edit the question I'm going to add some extra code to show you how I have implemented the ``localstorage``. Also I'm not sure if the promise is going to work in ``ie8``. So far what I have tried is add in the ``document.redy`` a function to check if the select is filled and when is filled set the ``select`` but I think is not efficient.

Comment: `document.ready` is generally useless in angular views

Comment: @gon250 never ever use jquery with angularJS

Comment: @Fals I'm using ``angular.element(document).ready``

Answer (score 1):

You would store whatever data you want to display in the views in an Angular service. You would then inject that service into your controllers. The data persists in the service because services in Angular are [singletons](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/guide/services).

Answer (score 0):

Check out ui router extras http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky Try using sticky states, but beware as controllers on that view will not get reinitialized when you go back to that view.

**Example usage,**

```
$stateProvider
        //home state
         .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'views/layout/home.html'
        })   
        //Client States
        .state('home.clients', {
            url: '/clients',
            views: {
                'clientTab@home':{
                 templateUrl: 'views/client/clients.html'
                 }
            },
             deepStateRedirect: true,
             sticky: true
           });
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```